# How to completely uninstall Android_x86, if it was installed from Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, android, alien

I have been searching how to do it, but all results are instructions for Windows 10 users. Because of that, I need help to uninstall this OS from my machine.

I have installed it using the `alien` package, as per [www.android-x86.org recommendation](https://www.android-x86.org/releases/releasenote-cm-x86-14-1-r4.html).

```
sudo apt install alien
sudo alien -ci cm-x86-14.1-r4.x86_64.rpm
```

My OS

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.10 (Groovy Gorilla)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 2
```

output of `dpkg -L cm-x86`:

```
dpkg-query: warning: files list file for package 'cm-x86' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
Package 'cm-x86' does not contain any files (!)
```

output of `dpkg -L cm-x86`, **after running `sudo apt remove cm-x86`**:

```
dpkg-query: package 'cm-x86' is not installed
Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show us the complete output of `dpkg -l | grep cm-86`

Comment: @user535733 this command line outputs nothing.

Comment: Then what leads you to believe that the package is installed?

Comment: @user535733 because I can boot into Android_x86, using grub

Comment: Run Gparted, delete the Android partition, update grub. That's it. I don't really see the relevance to Ubuntu, since it's not Ubuntu software. It's a whole different OS.

Comment: @user535733 I'm not sure if I did it, correctly. There was no partition, but a folder in the root directory called `/cm-x86-14.1-r4`. I deleted it and removed its entries from grub.

Comment: Oh, typo: Show us the complete output of `dpkg -L cm-x86` (the package name). Avoid deleting files placed by the package manger -- that merely causes bigger problems.

Comment: updated question body with requested output @user535733

Comment: Read your output: Wrong package name. Try again.

Comment: @user535733 updated the body. Sorry for that! Now I understand what you meant by "typo" and I was able to run `sudo apt remove cm-x86`. Is that all it takes to uninstall this OS?

Comment: Normally that's all. However this wasn't a native deb package, so we cannot be certain.